# DevOps pipeline submodule another collection

Tags: git, azure-devops, permissions

Hello i got Azure DevOps 2022 OnPrem, and got a pipeline to build a app, this app got a submodule in another collection. On checkout i got

```
steps:

- checkout: self
  submodules: true
  persistCredentials: true
```

When run the pipeline the checkout of modules in same collection works but the project in the other collection gives the error.

> fatal: unable to access '/Common/Extensions/_git/Extensions/':
> The requested URL returned error: 400 Unable to fetch in submodule
> path 'deps/Extensions'; trying to directly fetch
> 82cbdc59914453e722aad8b357fff13c224b4284: fatal: unable to access
> '/Common/Extensions/_git/Extensions/': The requested URL returned
> error: 400 fatal: Fetched in submodule path 'deps/Extensions', but it
> did not contain 82cbdc59914453e722aad8b357fff13c224b4284. Direct
> fetching of that commit failed.

The main project is on collection

- ClientApp/

The submodule is on collection

- Common/

I try setting

- Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines
- Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines

to false (was already) but not works.

I also tried to add the Build ClientApp user to the Commoncollection but it doesn't appear

Any hits?

Thanks